# How to give every thread a new number with a constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

Ok so my issue is that I have an array of threads, let's say 12 Threads and this is my code of my main method.

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));


        for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){

            threads[i] = new ThreadNumber();
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }
```

Then how do I implement a constructor that helps me give every Thread a number so that I have a variable for my run method where I can print it.

```
    static class ThreadNumber extends Thread{

//        public ThreadNumber(){
//            nummer +=1;
//        }

        public void run(){
            if(getName().substring(7).equals("0")){
               // System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");
            }
            else if(getName().substring(7).equals("1")){
                //System.out.println("1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer. Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.");
            }
            else if(getName().substring(7).equals("2")){
               // System.out.println("2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.");
            }
            else{
               // System.out.println(getName().substring(7) + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + getName().substring(7) + " bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around, " + (Integer.parseInt(getName().substring(7)) - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall.");
            }
        }
    }
```

For this example it still works with using the getName method of the Thread class but if I implement Runnable instead of Thread then it doesnt work anymore and I think it only works with a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `static` keyword. So your constructor will look like this:

```
private static int n;

public ThreadNumber() {
    setName(String.valueOf(++n));
}
```

P.S. `String.valueOf()` is using, because `setName()` accepts string only.

Comment: Thanks that does work yeah, I just totally forgot about the set methods.

Comment: Be aware that it is not thread-safe. If more than one thread creates new threads, numbering may become inconsistent.